# How do I connect to remoting-connector using Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, wildfly, jmx, remoting, visualvm

**Does anyone have ideas how to get closer to solve my issue?**

I am struggeling with a remote connection to jmx of my Wildfly server .

## Environment

> WildFly 10.0.0 Final
>
> JDK 1.8.0_66
>
> Domain Mode
>
> dedicated remoting socket
>
> dedicated remoting connector

I introduced a dedicated remoting connector, since I want to give access to jmx only by this port and keep my management on another port. I defined the security-realm as well as some users in there.

## Way of work

I tried several connection strings in the syntax "service:jmx:://:. But no protocol works:

- remote
- http-remoting-jmx
- remoting-jmx
- remote+http
- remoting-remote
- remoting-jmx

## Errors

This appears in the server.log of my WF server

> DEBUG [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (default I/O-5) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: XNIO000804: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856

## Snippet of profile configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">
    <endpoint/>
    <connector name="remoting" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
</subsystem>
```

I would like to use VisualVM on my Windows client to connect, so I used the Wildfly jconsole.bat and adjusted the executables for using VisualVM.

## Environment script for VisualVM

```
@echo off
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem jconsole script for Windows
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem
rem A script for running jconsole with the remoting-jmx libraries on the classpath. 

rem $Id$
set JBOSS_HOME="C:\local\wildfly_10.0"
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.8.0_66"


@if not "%ECHO%" == ""  echo %ECHO%
@if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

if "x%JAVA_HOME%" =="x" (
    echo JAVA_HOME environment variable has not been set - please set and re-run!
    goto :EOF
)

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
set "DIRNAME=%~dp0%"
) else (
set DIRNAME=.\
)

pushd %DIRNAME%..
set "RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
popd

if "x%JBOSS_HOME%" == "x" (
set "JBOSS_HOME=%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%" 
)

pushd "%JBOSS_HOME%"
set "SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
popd

if "%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%" NEQ "%SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME%" (
    echo WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.
)

set DIRNAME=

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
set "PROGNAME=%~nx0%"
) else (
set "PROGNAME=jdr.bat"
)

rem Setup JBoss specific properties
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "x" (  
echo JAVA_HOME is not set. Unable to locate the jars needed to run jconsole.
goto END
)

rem Find jboss-modules.jar, or we can't continue
if exist "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar" (
    set "RUNJAR=%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar"
) else (
echo Could not locate "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar".
echo Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.
goto END
)

rem Set default module root paths
if "x%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%" == "x" (
set  "JBOSS_MODULEPATH=%JBOSS_HOME%\modules"
)

rem Setup The Classpath
set CLASSPATH=


call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\remoting\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\remoting-jmx\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\remoting3\remoting-jmx\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\remoting3\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logging\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\xnio\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\xnio\nio\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\sasl\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\marshalling\main
call :SearchForJars %JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\marshalling\river\main


"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jvisualvm.exe" "-cp:a" "%CLASSPATH%" 

:END
goto :EOF

:SearchForJars
pushd %1
for %%j in (*.jar) do call :ClasspathAdd %1\%%j
popd
goto :EOF

:ClasspathAdd
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%1


:EOF
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but one small note is for the class path you can use the `jboss-client.jar` uber JAR which is in `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/client`.

I *think* the message means you're trying to connect with something like HTTP but you're using the remoting `<connector/>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

For Wildfly 10.1:

Run jconsole.sh from the wildfly/bin directory.

Connect with service:jmx:remote+http://server:port

and the management user you added.

You can see the port in the log output

```
10:20:36,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://server:10090/management
```